# how do I write a TS generic for something where the inferred T will be an array?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

so, I have a function that operates in an RxJS stream. It gets a single object (say of type 'IPerson') through the stream and its own argument is an array of strings for date fields I want it to parse on that object. I can use this:

```
function dateParser<T, K extends keyof T>(dateFields: K[])
```

and now if I call with a typo like `dateParser(['dateofbiiiirth'])` then TS will warn me

but, I want to have the same safety for a similar function that works on an array passed through the stream (say of type 'IPerson[]')

and obviously here the TS warning goes off for any of my key strings because it expects the keys of array like 'length' etc, not the keys of an individual instance of my interface.

I tried using

```
function dateParser<T[], K extends keyof T>(dateFields: K[])
```

and it doesn't appear that that is allowed, it just errors the whole function

how would I write a generic that says "if you infer SomeType[] then make sure the strings given are keys of a *single one* of that type you got an array of"?

**more explanation based on comment below**

so say I have this:

```
getSearchResults(): Observable<IMemberSearchResult> {
    return this.http
        .get<IServiceResponse<IMemberSearchResult>>(`${this.serviceUrl}`)
        .pipe(
            stripApiResponse(),
            dateParser(['DateOfBirth', 'LastVisitDate'])
            );
}
```

and this:

```
getSearchResults(): Observable<IMemberSearchResult[]> {
    return this.http
        .get<IServiceResponse<IMemberSearchResult[]>>(`${this.serviceUrl}`)
        .pipe(
            stripApiResponse(),
            dateParser(['DateOfBirth', 'LastVisitDate'])
            );
}
```

the only difference is whether they are getting search result (single) or search result (array)

assume IMemberSearchResult interface *does* have a DateOfBirth prop but does not have a LastVisitDate prop

using the single one, TS correctly infers T, and it correctly puts an error under *only* 'LastVisitDate' . . . using an array, TS interprets `<T, K extends keyof T>` for the type it inferred and wants K to be the keys that go with Array, not the actual keys of your search result interface. Because of this it things both strings are errors. how would I re-write that so that it properly knows what keys to check for?

Comment: This function has no way to infer what `T` is. Can you create a minimal reproducible example in a [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) that shows how you are intending to use this function and shows the error you are getting?

Comment: I can't seem to get it working in the playground because it involves too much intersection of angular and rxjs and won't let me import everything I need.

I can try to explain better? will update main question again

Comment: `T extends any[]` is the constraint for the question in the title

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that a RxJS operator is a function that should return a function whose entry argument is an Observable and the return type is another observable, you don't need to set the type.

```js
import { Observable, OperatorFunction, of } from 'rxjs';

function dateParser<T>(keys: (keyof T)[]): OperatorFunction<T[], T[]> {
  return function(source: Observable<T[]>): Observable<T[]> {
    return source
  }
}

interface MyInterface {
  a: string;
  b: number;
}

const obj: MyInterface[] = [{
  a: '', b: 3
}]

const source = of(obj).pipe(
  dateParser(['a']), // Correct
  dateParser(['c']) // Incorrect
);
```

Here is an [example that works](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-xwmsxj)

Comment: this is the closest answer so far. the issue is with arrays . . . so
`myStream$.pipe(dateParser<MyInterface[]>(['a']), // correct but errors anyhow`

so, getting keyof myInterface is easy, but how do I get it to do the same with keyof myInterface[] instead of erroring because it infers the keys of Array in general instead

Comment: of course! `OperatorFunction<T[], T[]>`

haha one of those things that looks so obvious _after_ you see it working haha. thanks so much!

Comment: Two pairs of eyes are better than one :) Don't hesitate to mark as accepted if it solves the issue

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like:

```
function callWithValidKeys<T>(objects: T[], keys: (keyof T)[]) {}
```

The important thing is to type the *argument* as the array (`objects T[]`). This means that `T` will represent the member type of the array, and not the array itself. Then `keys` can be be an array of the keys of that member type.

Example usage:

```
interface IPerson { name: string, age: number }
const people: IPerson[] = [
    { name: "Foo", age: 20 },
    { name: "Bar", age: 50 },
]

callWithValidKeys(people, ["name", "age"])

// Type '"badKey"' is not assignable to type '"name" | "age"'.(2322)
callWithValidKeys(people, ["name", "badKey"])
```

---

Note that in order for this to work, you need to provide the array it's operating on, otherwise typescript has no idea what the member type is.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBAhgGzQdRlAFgNXRgBMBpAUwE8BnAHgBUA+ACjgCMArc6agLkXoBtALoAaRAGsqfRMymU4wAQEoRyxAG8AvgFgAUPphgo5AE7AUEcogCSABTPUEmxGBQBbcv2pRTRgObiKP5eriDubGaIunoQCD6IAA7kcIloofaOCCKIALyIgvqIxS5unvwARABicHAVQSH8AEwADNGiRSUarh6hFQBCKKb1iMGhAKxtWh16wvr6qBjYeIRoJBQ0zMmp6eKCFWXkIxVjFcLK83oA9FcClMmIAOQVbChkVBWPiDDUrnBQo2o1Bg-jcbHSiCgcEh92sz0OFUQAB9ECcQp8AHTMJoAZiaTQusXQWBwBCI7022zS5D2B16x1eFLOhKAA)